# Can't set disablelastaccess to 0

Tags: azure

I'm running a Windows VM in Azure. I want to find out which files in a specific directory are not being accessed. I tried to run:
"fsutil behavior set disablelastaccess 0"
in order to look at referenced dates, but I am not an administrator.
How can I do this if I can't run fsutil?

Answer (score 0):

There should be no restriction on running this command on an Azure virtual machine. Make sure that you:

1. Have logged in with a user that is a member of at least the Local Administrators group (assuming there's no Active Directory in this scenario, which could potentially complicate things).
2. Have opened powershell as an administrator. You can right click and run the shell as an administrator of the GUI is installed, or you can open PowerShell as an unprivileged user and then `Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs` (or use the older `runas` command, if you feel a bit legacy).